# Operator normality for different inner products

Tags: partial-differential-equations, inner-products, wave-equation, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

I have a wave equation in PDE form, defined as

$$
\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} + div(u) = 0, \\
\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial t} + \nabla_i P - \mu \Delta u_i = 0.
$$
Here $(P, u_i)$ are the acoustic pressure and velocity perturbation fields. I also supplement all the necessary boundary conditions.

There is another (yet equivalent) form of the equation above:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u_i}{\partial t^2} - \Delta u_i - \mu \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Delta u_i = 0.
$$
This is a Helmholtz equation with a dissipative term, proportional to $\mu$.

As we can expect, the spectrum of these equations are complex, with negative real part representing the decay rate (since $\mu > 0$). And therefore the operator $R u_i = \left( \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial t^2} - \Delta - \mu \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Delta \right) u_i$ is non-normal.

Since the equation is linear, let's perform a Fourier transform. We get:

$$
- \omega^2 u_i - \Delta u_i - i \omega \mu\Delta u_i = 0.
$$

Now, let's define the following inner product:

$$
\left\langle a, b \right\rangle = \int_\Omega a b \ \mathrm{d}x,
$$
which involves no complex conjugation. Under this inner product, the adjoint operator
$$
R^\dagger \lambda_i = \omega^2 \lambda_i - \Delta \lambda_i - i \omega \mu\Delta \lambda_i = 0
$$
is clearly the same as the direct one.

My questions is:

1. Am I correct that the operator $R$ is self-adjoint under this inner product?
2. Is it normal then?
3. What problems can I expect in my further analysis if I consider this inner product?

Comment: Did you consider the boundary terms from the laplace transform?

Comment: @maxmilgram Thank you! Yes, for simplicity I consider Dirichlet / Neumann BCs for now, so the adjoint boundary conditions are the same as the direct ones.

Comment: I meant with respect to time. Usually, when performing the laplace transform you get boundary terms for $t=0^+$.

Comment: This is indeed a good question. Yes, the operator is not self-adjoint in time domain. This is why I try to understand the spectral domain problem, i.e., d/dt -> s. We don't need initial conditions in this case, I believe.

Comment: I dont see any reason why you would not get them. E.g. $\mathcal{L}(f')(s)=s\mathcal{L}(f)(s)-f(0^+)$

Comment: Ok, I can put it in a different way: consider I work with the spectral problem from the beginning. Therefore, as we want to study the eigenvalue problem, the term you are referring to, does not appear. Another way to explain what I mean, is to use Fourier transform instead.

Comment: If this is standard procedure I apologize for not knowing it. However I honestly don't think you can argue like that especially the point about the fourier transform makes no sense since it would give different signs and an $i$ in front of the former first derivative. Of course you can simply look at the equation you ended up with but the question is if and how it relates to the original problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94598/discussion-between-krishal-and-maxmilgram).